# How do you use set the right config (dev/prod) on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I was reading this article: http://12factor.net/config
And it mentioned that the right way to separate dev/prod config is to use environment variables. Was wondering how we can achieve it on Google App Engine? I have client secrets in the prod app which I would not like to check into the revision control (GitHub) since we sometimes outsource some development, and yet I would like to be able to deploy with a "git push"/ deploy with the correct secrets. I use this check for dev vs prod:

IS_DEV_APPSERVER = 'development' in os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').lower()

Comment: Are you using separate App IDs for your development and production environments?  If so, you can do something like this (Java): `isProduction = ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment().getAppId().equals("your-production-app-id");`. If you're using Python, you can look at the [App Identity API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/appidentity/)

Comment: No, is that the best practice - to use a separate App ID for prod? How is this check different from the one I mentioned? I still have the problem that I should not be checking in the client secrets into the VCS.